# Yii2: position CSS at the bottom of <body>

Tags: html, css, yii2

Yii2 positions JS files at the bottom of `<body>` by default, and it can be changed via `public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_*];` setting.

But how to do the same for CSS? I would like CSS to be positioned right before JS scripts at the bottom of a page. Something like:

`public $cssOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END];`

But this does not work.

Reason for this is site optimization by recommendations of Google PageSpeed.

**EDIT:**

Looks like yii2 does not support it, but maybe there is some technic or extension that allows to keep AssetBundle's logic, and also gives an ability to choose desired position for CSS?

Comment: Add css manually at bottom : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/filename.css">

Comment: But then I can't use AssetBundles for these css...

Comment: Why would you do that? CSS needs to be in the `head`, not before the closing `body` element. You can use `style-scoped` which is [not really supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped).

Comment: I need it to optimize css delivery according to PageSpeed recommendations: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery (there is some JS in english version, but other language translations offer simpler solution: to just place ```<link>``` after ```<html>```).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yii 2, if you register CSS then it will be added in head tag only. you can't add it below body tag. If you will add manually then it is possible but there is one problem with this solution. The third party extension which you will install, they will register their CSS in the head. So, I will suggest you to add CSS at the head section :)

Comment: Thanks. After a long time I did not find a way to do it with Yii. Looks like if it is required to split css files to critical path ones and other, then it is required to use some other tool/approach outside of Yii.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible right now using `$cssOptions` or `registerCssFile()`.
You need to add it manually in layout in desired position.